# Android device sends message after uninstalling an application

Tags: android

Is it possible to send a message from android device to server after un installing an application. we have already installed that application on device.

Comment: Not from application that just get unistalled...

Comment: Check [this link](https://www.google.com.tr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20check%20if%20the%20app%20is%20uninstalled%20android)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if the app is uninstalled, the app no longer exists on the device and therefore has no code to run to "send a message".

Comment: is it not possible to send message just before uninstall app on device? Any other possibility I just want to inform server via message that app is uninstalled successfully.

Comment: @Nixi: There is no support for this.